Interpretation of QR "values" (a la singular values)?
Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with $m>n$ and $\text{rank}A=n$.
There exists $\hat{Q}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with orthonormal columns and $\hat{R}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ upper triangular with positive diagonal such that $A=\hat{Q}\hat{R}$ and $\text{Col}A_{:,1:k} = \text{Col}\hat{Q}_{:,1:k}$ for all $k=1,\ldots,n$.
Is there an interpretation similar in spirit to that of singular values, in the sense that I can look at the decay of values of the diagonal of $\hat{R}$ (I recognize they're not sorted) and make a statement about the amount of variation in the span of the first $r$ columns of $A$ (where $r<n$) relative to all the columns?
My intuition is that there is, perhaps because of the successive spanning property, but I cannot find anything about this in any book or online resource.
My use-case is a bit odd in that I am looking at columns that are ordered (so pivoted QR is not relevant), and I'm interested in some notion of accumulation of variation in the data over the first $r$ columns. Therefore, I don't think SVD is relevant since the left singular vectors do not have to successively span the same space as the columns of $A$.
Thanks!

You could interpret $\hat R_{k,k}$ as giving the "extent" to which $A_{:,k}$ lies beyond the span of columns $A_{:,1},\dots, A_{:,k-1}$. To make things a bit more precise: consider the least squares problem
$$
\min_{x \in \Bbb R^{k-1}} |A_{:, \ 1:k-1} x - A_i|^2
$$
The minimum attained is given by $\hat R_{k,k}^2$. You could make this into some relative measure by consider the ratio $\frac{R_{k,k}^2}{|A_{:,k}|^2}$.
